# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not being called, i have tried every method on overflow, any other reason can cause this bug?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have checked out every similar question and every answer,I have implemented with code. I have set

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Check out  the method name of what i expect of is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` . There is 
no `UITapGestureRecognizer`.UI Hierarchy shows nothing on the cell.
I have not implemented the  method: `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath`, `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

My custom cell is clean without xib.
Tapping the cell doesn't work ,but dragging the cell works and calls  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Is there anyone know any other reason that can cause this bug?
wired! I have try take this UITableViewController into a demo and show, but in this demo it worked. Maybe some method in my project block didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How can find which method has blocked? How can I catch the tap event ,and find out which method has happened

Comment: maybe you can show the code you have?

Comment: Also check userInteractionEnabled of particular cell.

Comment: Do you have any UIButton on your TableView Cell?

Comment: sorry the project is huge,that i can't  show the code clearly.

Comment: the cell userInteractionEnabled is yes. there is no button on my cell , i have try delete all my content ,still not work

Comment: You better show the relevant parts of the code. It might be as simple as a typo in the name of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableViewController` inside a `UIViewController`, please check if you set the `delegate` & `datasource` of the `UITableViewController` or not.

Comment: the table show the cell ,the cell can call didSelectRowAtIndexPath by dragging not the tapping , that's the problem

Comment: Hi Tom, can you please show the code where you are facing the problem. It will help in finding the problem. Or please create a test project and copy that file and try to replicate the issue. Then inspect each element of UITableViewCell. It will definitely help.

Comment: wired! I have try take this UITableViewController into a demo and show, but in this demo it worked. Maybe  some method in my project block didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How can find which method has blocked? How can I catch the tap event ,and find out which method has happened

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

check return height is correct. You can set cell `backgroundColor` to check cell frame.